# Parse list to bst in ML

Tags: list, binary-search-tree, ml

a note a similar problem can be found at: 
[standard ml make bst out of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954177/standard-ml-make-bst-out-of-a-list)

I have a list which i'm loading from the portion and the variable in there is called test, i have tested it and it works.

```
use "mllistr.txt";
datatype 'a BST = Nil | Node of 'a * 'a BST * 'a BST;

fun leftchild (Node(data,left,right)) = left
 | leftchild Nil = raise Empty;
fun rightchild (Node(data,left,right)) = right
 | rightchild Nil = raise Empty;
fun insert (x, Nil) = Node(x, Nil, Nil)
 |insert (x, Node(y, left, right) ) =
        if x<y then Node(y, insert(x,left), right)
        else Node(y, left, insert(x, right) );

(*test this var is the tree unmade but as a list*)
fun makeTree ([], bst) = Empty
 | makeTree ((x::xs), bst) = insert (x) (makeTree xs bst);
```

I have tried a bunch of formats for the line of code directly above and this is jus the current iteration of failed attempts to fix the issue.

Before i even attempt to put in the code:

```
makeTree test Empty
```

I know its going to fail because of this error:

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
operator domain: (int * int BST) list * 'Z
operand:         (int * int BST) list
in expression:
    makeTree xs
stdIn:19.29-19.57 Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch]
  operator: int BST
  in expression:
    (insert x) ((makeTree xs) bst)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, i still don't understand Ml that well

Comment: Looks like you may just need to change `makeTree xs bst` to `makeTree (xs, bst)`. This question and its answers has a decent explanation of the difference, but it should be covered in any intro ML course/book/etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405761/typed-fp-tuple-arguments-and-curriable-arguments

Comment: Forgot to update this, it ended up being the datastructure i was using, should have been: datatype btree = Empty
 | Node of int * btree * btree;